With postgres table partitioning by list (of varchar), will the varchars be stored physically in each row?
When having a table that gets partitioned by list, using a varchar field (or text field) that contains long strings, will those strings be physically stored in each partition and hence increasing the size of the table? Or is postgres "smart" and doesn't store it physically because it knows what the value of that column is for each partition.
I used the pg_column_size function on the column and it shows me that it uses bytes (like it would on an unpartitioned table), but I'm not sure if I can trust it.

The values get stored normally in the partition tables. If you create a partition FOR VALUES IN ('x', 'y', 'z'), how else would PostgreSQL know the value?
I think the root of the problem is that you store these long strings in the table. Presumably there are not too many different values for the long strings, otherwise list partitioning wouldn't be feasible. So the best solution might be to create a lookup table for these long strings and store the (integer) primary key in the table you want to partition. Then the overhead would be much less, and you would avoid redundancy on top of that.

I thought that when using PARTITION BY LIST (column) then postgres could know about it since it would always be exactly one value per partition and not multiple ones like in your example. I agree with what the rest that you are writing - I'm trying to evaluate if this optimization is necessary or not.
